# How to add file to Sub-Folder of Google Drive using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

I have spent hours trying to add Subfolder to google drive and also to add a file to subfolders but in vain.  Below code works to upload file to drive but I'm not able to add a reference to subset folder to add to them. I have referred to below links but don't know how to convert lines like below to vb.net. any help will be much appreciated.

```
body.Parents = New List<ParentReference>() { New ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };
```

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert#.net

Please help.

```
 Dim vFIle As New File()
        vFIle.Title = "My document.txt"
        vFIle.Description = "A test document"
        vFIle.MimeType = "text/plain"

        Dim ByteArray As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
        Dim Stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(ByteArray)

        Dim UploadRequest As FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload = Service.Files.Insert(vFIle, Stream, vFIle.MimeType)
        UploadRequest.Upload()
        Dim file As File = UploadRequest.ResponseBody

---- > test2

Dim filetoUp As String = "C:\install log.txt"
If Service.ApplicationName <> "Google Drive VB Dot Net" Then CreateService()
Dim folderId As String = "1UDFFDxi25Hfdgh34sdefcciRE67qzisdRL"
'Dim FodlersList As New List(Of String) From {folderId, "1UDFFDxi25Hfdgh34sdefcciRE67qzisdRLX1", "1UDFFDxi25Hfdgh34sdefcciRE67qzisdRLX2"}
'Dim plist As New List(Of ParentList) From {folderId}

Dim fileMetadata = New File()
With fileMetadata
    .Title = "new.txt"
    .MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    '.Parents = New List(Of String) From {folderId}
    .Parents(0) = Service.Files.List(folderId)
End With


'System.IO.FileMode.Open
Dim stream = New System.IO.FileStream(filetoUp, System.IO.FileMode.Open)

Dim request
request = Service.Files.Insert(fileMetadata, stream, "text/plain")
'fields is not valid member
'request.Fields = "id" 
request.Upload()
```

Comment: If you have C# code, you can convert it to VB.NET reliably using a free online converter. There are several, such as this one: https://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Thanks for useful tool. Still not able to make it work. anymore tips?

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: @Craig 'm actually new to all this. 'm blindly trying multiple things but won't work. Below is one of the error.

Dim fileMetadata = New File()
        With fileMetadata
            .Title = "new.txt"
            .MimeType = "text/plain"
            .Parents = New List(Of String) From {"1UDFFDxi25Hfdgh34sdefcciRE67qzisdRL"}
            .Parents(0) = Service.Files.List(folderId)

system.invalidcastexception 'unable to cast object of type 'system.collections.generic.list '1[system.string]' to type 'system.collections.gegeric.Ilist' 1 [googel.apis.drive.v2.data.parentRefenrece]'

Comment: Can you create a New List(Of Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.parentReference) ?

Comment: @Alessandro thank you. Would it be possible to show me an example or link I'm completely lost here.

Comment: Please share the entire code you wrote that produces the above error and I will show you what I mean.

Comment: @Alessandro, please refer to ---- > test2 section from the first post. I updated the code. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Approach

Our File resource has a Parents parameter that accepts a List of `ParentReference` Objects. A simple `ParentReference` Object has a `Id` parameter representing the folder Id in Google Drive.

Here you are trying to implicitly cast a string into a `ParentList`.

```
Dim folderId As String = "1UDFFDxi25Hfdgh34sdefcciRE67qzisdRL"
Dim plist As New List(Of ParentList) From {folderId}
```

I'm not sure this `ParentList` class exists in Google Api but this is what causes your program to fail.

You should instead create a List of `ParentReference`, like this:

```
Dim folderId = "your-folder-id"
Dim TheFile As New File()
TheFile.Title = "My document"
TheFile.Description = "A test document"
TheFile.MimeType = "text/plain"
TheFile.Parents = New List(Of ParentReference) From {New ParentReference() With {.Id = folderId}}
```

### Reference

[Drive v2 Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files)

[Drive API v2 .Net Guide](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/latest/api/Google.Apis.Drive.v2.html)

Comment: thank you so much for the help and providing additional resources/links. It worked for me.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it helped. It's good praxis to accept the answer so it will result useful to other users looking for it. [How to accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)